# How to make lists horizontally scroll-able only in Smaller Devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing one of my website using Bootstrap. I want the lists `<li>` not to collapse when opened in smaller screen, but they must be horizontally scrollable only on a smaller devices.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="my-menubar">
        <ul >
            <li id="e1" ><a href="#"><button id="event1">Menu 1</button></a></li>
            <li id="e2" ><a href="#"><button id="event2">Menu 2</button></a></li>
            <li id="e3" ><a href="#"><button id="event3">Menu 3</button></a></li>
            <li id="e4" ><a href="#"><button id="event4">Menu 4</button></a></li>
            <li id="e5" ><a href="#"><button id="event5">Menu 5</button></a></li>
            <li id="e6" ><a href="#"><button id="event6">Menu 6</button></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#my-menubar { 
height: auto;
background-color: #ffffff; }
#my-menubar li { 
list-style: none;
float:left; }
#my-menubar button { 
width:auto; 
margin:4px; }
#my-menubar a {
padding: 15px 45px 0px 45px; }
#event1, #event2, #event3, #event4,#event5, #event6 {
width:115px;
height:35px;
color: white;
border-radius:40px;
border-style:none;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #27413f; }
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need css media queries

```
/* !Phone vertical */
@media (max-width: 520px) { 
    .menu { 
        overflow-y: scroll;
        // apply other styles to
    }
}

/* !Phone horizontal, tablet vertical */
@media (max-width: 760px) { 
}

/* !Tablet horizontal */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
}
```

Add this beneath your other css rules and it will apply the styles when the media query is satisfied, I.E the screen width is less than 520px for the first one.

See [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and [this](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or just google for more info.